# Using AlertDialog (MultiChoice Checkboxes) crashes my app

Tags: android, android-widget

There is a similar question on SO but i reckon my problem lies elsewhere or I'm missing something rather fundamental here.

I do have a unique ID set for my dialog : `static final int DAYS_DIALOG_ID = 1;`

I also have a class member variable : `private TextView textViewSelectDayOfWeek;`

In my overriden method `onCreate()`, i have :

```
textViewSelectDayOfWeek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSelectDayOfWeek);
textViewSelectDayOfWeek.setOnClickListener(this);
```

So basically, i caputre my TextView defined in XML file in a variable and i set it's listener.

In my `onClick(view v)`, there's a switch with the following case that is supposed to handle clicks on the TextView that is supposed to handle opening my dialog (do note that the aforementioned switch uses `v.getId()`):

```
case R.id.textViewSelectDayOfWeek:
            showDialog(DAYS_DIALOG_ID);
            break;
```

My overriden method `onCreateDialog(int id)` also contains a switch statement that uses the ID provided. The case that handles this particular problem-causing dialog is the following:

```
case DAYS_DIALOG_ID:
            final CharSequence[] daysOfWeek = { "@string/stringMonday"}; // 7 days, skimming unimportant stuff
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("@string/stringSelectDayDialogTitle")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(daysOfWeek,
                                    new boolean[] {true, true, true, true, true}, // Sets first 5 days as checked by default
                                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int day, boolean isChecked) {
                                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), daysOfWeek[day], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                                   })
                                   .create();
```

Now, if i click on the TextView with ID textViewSelectDayOfWeek, my app crashes.

I tried `Toast`ing a message in `onClick()` right before i call `showDialog(DAYS_DIALOG_ID)` and the message does NOT appear before my app crashes.

What can i do to fix this problem ? I believe i mentioned all the important bits of my code but feel encouraged to request anything that might help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error when it crashes?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 I've been trying to launch it on my phone (2.2 Android Platform), the usual " has stopped unexpectedly ".

Comment: If your phone is connected to your development machine, in ddms --logcat you will see exception message. That stack trace would be realy helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I certainly hope this helps someone.

As thinksteep mentioned, the exception thrown is actually fairly useful :)

I had an array of 7 week days and i supplied an incomplete array containing only 5 boolean values, which were to define whether the day is checked or unchecked by default, thinking the remaining values would be initialized with a default value of some kind.